# How do I create a user control for this kind of display with databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, data-controls

I have `css`. But I don't know how to create a user control for this kind of display.

Title is the department name and the below mentioned radio buttons are statuses for each department.  Now department can be multiple depending on the values in the database.
This one box can contain only two department lists and the new box needs to be created as soon as 2 departments are filled into this.

How could I create user controls for this type to bind it to the datatable?

I am reading about `DynamicDataField` but it seems to be of no use.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a1a4ec51c6.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a1a4ec51c6.jpg)

Here fields encircled is department and its statuses

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 GridView Control. One for each box.